# Give a Pure Azure AD User local Administrator rights

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have a company that is 100% setup in Office365 and Azure.  New laptops are running Windows 10 Pro and being setup to allow the user to login using their Azure AD / Office 365 credentials.  This works great as it's the same password as Office365 and there is no on prem AD.  But I have not been able to get these users any local administrator rights locally or through Azure AD.  Anyone dealt with this and/or found a work around?

I originally thought I could just login as an Administrator and give the account local admin rights, but the account doesn't exist in the local users and groups like it does with standard AD.  The account is indeed on the machine, but I assume due to it being brand new in Windows 10 and Azure AD there's not a local way to assign admin rights?

Any help would be great, thanks a bunch.

Comment: This belongs on Server Fault.

Comment: There is a thread on that at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d6a41fab-8761-467f-b9a2-6949aabd4efa/make-azure-adusers-local-admin-on-azure-adjoined-client?forum=WindowsAzureAD

Comment: Tried flagging it as needing migration to serverfault, but the list of sites it gave me were superuser, dba, stats and meta

Comment: "net localgroup administrators AzureAD\JohnDoe /add"  http://superuser.com/questions/982336/how-do-i-add-azure-active-directory-user-to-local-administrators-group